# How to Convert Dwg File TO Pdf File Using Design Automation / Autodesk Platform API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autocad-plugin, autodesk-designautomation, autocad-scripts

We want to convert dwg file to pdf using design automation or autodesk platform services api.
We have created a autocad plugin, that creates the desired dwg file and upload it oss bucket, we want to convert dwg file present on oss to pdf file.

We found this [Design automation api to convet dwg to pdf](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2/developers_guide/overview/) , but this version2 of desing automation api is depreacted and couldn't find any anything related to it on version 3 of api.

Please let us know how it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V2 is deprecated, use this sample https://github.com/MadhukarMoogala/FDA_PlotToPdf_v3